# how to touch files like report-07/05/13

Tags: command-line, files, date

when I want to touch files like `report-05/07/13` with command `touch report-$(date +%D)`
it gives me an error like this:

`touch: cannot touch`report-07/05/13': No such file or directory`

How can I build one?

By the way there is "NO FOLDER" it is JUST THE FILENAME.

Comment: Did the folder `report-07/` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the / sign is for path separator.

When you execute that command the result will be

report-07/05/13 but the shell will interpret like this

```
report-07 - Parent Directory 
05 - subdirectory
03 - filename
```

If indeed you want the directory report-07/05 then first you need to create it with:

```
mkdir -p report-`date +%m\/%d`
touch report-`date +%D`
```

If you want is just a file named date-M.D.Y then it will be easier to change the separator

```
touch report-`date +%m.%d.%y`
```

Comment: if i want to use `/` instead of `.` can i use `\/`?

Comment: no really, it will still search for the directory.
# touch test\/test
touch: cannot touch ‘test/test’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

`touch` can only create files, not directories. You have to create the directory first e.g. by calling `mkdir -p $(dirname report-$(date +%D))`.

The `-p` stands for *parent* and creates all missing directories in the given path. And `dirname` will strip of the last component of a path, passing only the directory to `mkdir`.

Answer (score 1):

Forward slashes are path separators in Unix, and as such cannot be used as part of a filename. If your specification is actually a full path, you can do this:

```
file=report-$(date +%D)
mkdir -p "${file%/*}"
touch "$file"
```